# Hibernate: How to map a class that "has-a" subclass to a single table?

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a class BacktestResult that contains a property BacktestInputs.  I want hibernate to create a single table that contains the contents of both.  Here's what I have so far:

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name="backtest_result")
    public class BacktestResult {
        @Id
        Long backtest_id;
        
        public int userId;
        BacktestInputs inputs;
    
        @OneToMany
        @OrderColumn(name="backtest_id")
        public BacktestChartDataPoint[] series;
//getters and setters
```

The BacktestChartDataPoint class looks like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="backtestchart_datapoint")
public class BacktestChartDataPoint {
    @Id
    public Long id;
    public Long backtest_id;
    
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="backtest_id", nullable=false, insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private BacktestResult backtestResult;
```

The BacktestInputs class looks like this:

```
public class BacktestInputs {
    public String strategy_name;
    public String version;
etc...
```

As long as I comment out the BacktestInputs in BacktestResult, hibernate correctly creates 3 tables:

1. backtest_result
2. backtest_result_series
3. backtestchart_datapoint

But I want the contents of BacktestInputs to be included in the BacktestResult table.  If I uncomment it, get error:

> Could not determine type for:
> net.tekknow.moneymachine.model.BacktestInputs, at table:
> backtest_result, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(inputs)]

What is the proper way to handle class hierarchy with "has-a" relationships, **NOT** "is-a" relationships?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to annotate the class `BacktestInputs` with `@Embeddable`
(see https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#embeddables)

Comment: Thank you for the link with nice clear examples.  I had used embeddables before for composite keys.  Didn't realize that had a more general purpose.  I will give it a try and come back to accept this answer if successful.